# using value of select statement in where clause of update, within if/else

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've refactored this script to use a select statement first to see if records exist in a certain table.

Right now, if nothing exists I'm just inserting. But my misunderstanding is now with the update. I already have `$content` as a variable.

But how do I take `existingContent` from my select and user it in the where clause of my update (which is called if an existing record is found in the select):

```
$content = $_POST['page_content'];
$panelID = $_POST['panel_type'];
$pageID = $_POST['page_id'];

$checkIfExists = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count, cont_id as existingContent FROM 
 panels WHERE panel_type_id = $panelID AND page_id = $pageID";

if($mysqlConn->query($checkIfExists)->count = 0){
     //working insert
else{
    $updateContent = "
    UPDATE content
        SET content = '$content'
        WHERE id = /*this would be existingContent from my select above*/
 }
```

Full updated code:

```
$content = $_POST['page_content'];
$panelID = $_POST['panel_type'];
$pageID = $_POST['page_id'];

$checkIfExists = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count, cont_id as existingContent FROM panels WHERE panel_type_id = $panelID AND page_id = $pageID";

$existingContent = $mysqlConn->query($checkIfExists);

if($existingContent->count == 0){

    $addContent = "
        INSERT INTO content(content)
        VALUES('$content');
    ";

    if ($mysqlConn->query($addContent) === TRUE) {
        $cont_id = $mysqlConn->insert_id;
        $data['last_insert_id'] = $cont_id;
        echo json_encode($data);
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $addContent . "<br>" . $mysqlConn->error;
    }


    $addPanel = "
        INSERT INTO panels(panel_type_id, page_id, cont_id)
        VALUES ('$panelID', '$pageID', '$cont_id');
    ";

    if ($mysqlConn->query($addPanel) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $addPanel . "<br>" . $mysqlConn->error;
    }

else{

    $updateContent = "
        UPDATE content
            SET content = '$content'
            WHERE id = $existingContent->existingContent;
    ";

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$content = $_POST['page_content'];
$panelID = $_POST['panel_type'];
$pageID = $_POST['page_id'];

$checkIfExists = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count, cont_id as existingContent FROM 
 panels WHERE panel_type_id = $panelID AND page_id = $pageID";

$existingContent = $mysqlConn->query($checkIfExists);

// You had an error in your IF statement you have used (=) instead of (==)
if($existingContent->count == 0){
     //working insert
else{
    $updateContent = "
    UPDATE content
        SET content = '$content'
        WHERE id = $existingContent->existingContent
 }
```

Suggestions your code if very unsecured you should be using value binding in your query.

This should get you started however, please do investigate value binding.

best of luck

Comment: Thank you! however, I'm now getting a 500 error. I posted my updated code above and my connection is working fine. Do you see any glaring issues?

Comment: Or at least a better way to debug this so that if I get a 500 I get an idea why

Comment: let me check one sec

Comment: 500 means there is a server issue, maybe server stopped working.. You can try a `die('here');` statement just before update query to see if it reaches that point.. This is how I break down my code on errors i go section by section to see where it breaks and re evaluate my code at that section. Let me know

Comment: I'll try that, It's currently happening even on the initial insert though. Before all of this I just had the three post variables and the two insert queries though and it was working fine

Comment: add the die statement to very top and work your way down just move it few lines at the time and see where it shows 500 and not die()

Comment: ok it's saying the $existingContent->count is an undefined property now?

Comment: So I'm past the 500 errors now but it's basically still inserting a new record because the count doesn't seem to work?

Comment: ahh ok @Whisou138 what you need to do is die($existingContent); and see how value is returned.. Maybe it is $existingContent->rows->count or what ever you will see it when you dump the variable

Answer (score 0):

```
$checkIfExists = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count, cont_id as existingContent FROM 
 panels WHERE panel_type_id = $panelID AND page_id = $pageID";

$stmt = $mysqlConn->prepare($checkIfExists); 
$stmt->execute(); 
$row = $stmt->fetch();

if($row['count'] == 0){
     //working insert
else{
    $updateContent = "
    UPDATE content
        SET content = '$content'
        WHERE id = {($row['cont_id']}
 }
```

maybe try this?